# Understanding the proof that the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers is $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I'm reading the following book: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring10/cos433/mathcs.pdf.

In page 26, they attempt to prove the following theorem using Induction:

> For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
>   $$1 + 2 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

In order to prove the theorem we need to prove the following statements:

- $P(0)$ is true.
- For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(n)$ implies $P(n + 1)$.

Proving the first one is easy:

$$P(0) = 0 = 0 * (0 + 1) / 2$$
$$= 0 = 0 * 1 / 2$$
$$= 0 = 0 / 2$$
$$= 0 = 0$$

In order to prove the second, they state the following:

$$1+2+\cdots + n + (n+1) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + (n+1) \tag{1}$$
$$ = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} \tag{2}$$

I don't understand how they get from (1) to (2) and how that proves that proves that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $P(n)$ implies $P(n + 1)$ is true.

I'm clearly missing something in the process. Can someone clear the fog for me?

Comment: For a tentaive simple explanation of *proof by induction*, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1069120/tips-and-tricks-for-understanding-induction-proofs-in-discrete-structures).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do the math.

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + (n+1) = \frac{n(n+1)+2(n+1)}{2} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}$$

For your second problem, note that you proved that $$1+2+\ldots+n+(n+1) = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}.$$

The initial statement is $1+2+\ldots+k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, with another letter. If you do $k=n+1$ you will get  $1+2+\ldots+(n+1) = \frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)}{2} = \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}$, and that is what you just proved.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}+\left(n+1\right) & =\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}+\frac{2\left(n+1\right)}{2}\\
 & =\frac{n^{2}+n+2n+2}{2}\\
 & =\frac{n^{2}+3n+2}{2}\\
 & =\frac{\left(n+2\right)\left(n+1\right)}{2}
\end{align*}